# Zooming Distortation

Tags: css, zooming

I am having a problem with my website, every time I adjust the zoom it distorts the page layout, I don't know what I've done wrong, please take a look at what I mean: [Distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khfla.png) [Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqmxG.jpg)

Comment: zooming will often distort the layout. Try setting fixed width for elements that should be on the same row, for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using **max-width** and **min-width** property for your layout in **CSS**

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML:

```
 <div class='pageHolder'>
    <div class='page'>1</div>
    <div class='page'>2</div>
    <div class='page'>3</div>
    </div>
```

with CSS:

```
.page {
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  width:20px;
  height:20px;              
  float: left;
}

.pageHolder{
 overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

Elements to clear floats is markup. It's like using `<br>` but for floats. Mixing markup and content is considered bad practice in semantic web.

Comment: Check it out.this is what you need